# Replacing duplicated words in python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, duplicates, words

I want to take a piece of text which looks like this:

```
Engineering will save the world from inefficiency. Inefficiency is a blight on the world and its humanity.
```

and return:

```
Engineering will save the world from inefficiency..is a blight on the . and its humanity.
```

That is, I want to remove duplicated words and replace them with "." 
This is how I started my code:

```
lines= ["Engineering will save the world from inefficiency.",
        "Inefficiency is a blight on the world and its humanity."]

def solve(lines):    
    clean_paragraph = []    
    for line in lines:    
        if line not in str(lines):
            clean_paragraph.append(line)
        print (clean_paragraph)    
        if word == word in line in clean_paragraph:
            word = "."              
     return clean_paragraph
```

My logic was to create a list with all of the worst in the strings and add each one to a new list, and then, if the word was already in the list, to replace it with ".". My code returns []. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't that return. "Engineering will save the world from inefficiency. . is a blight on . . and its humanity". If you are replacing all duplicate words

Comment: exactly, besides along with `world` word , the word `the` is also duplicated

Comment: yes, it should. I'm not sure where in my code I went wrong though

Comment: @user8827983 it should return a string OR a list?

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM:**

```
if word == word in line in clean_paragraph:
```

I'm not sure what you expect of this, but it will always be `False`.  Here it is gain with some clarifying parentheses:

```
if word == ((word in line) in clean_paragraph):
```

This evaluates `word in line`, which may be either Boolean value.  However, that value will *not* appear in the text of `clean_paragraph`, so the resulting expression is `False`.

**REPAIR**

Write the loops you're trying to encode:

```
for clean_line in clean_paragraph:
    for word in clean_line:
```

At this point, you'll have to figure out what you want for variable names.  You've tried to make a couple of variables stand for two different things at once (`line` and `word`; I fixed the first one).

You'll also have to learn to properly manipulate loops and their indices; part of the problem is that you've written more code at once than you can handle -- yet.  Back up, write one loop at a time, and print the results, so you know what you're getting into.  For instance, start with

```
for line in lines:

    if line not in str(lines):
        print("line", line, "is new: append")
        clean_paragraph.append(line)
    else:
        print("line", line, "is already in *lines*")
```

I think you'll spot another problem here -- one even earlier than the one I found.  Fix this, then add only one or two lines at a time, building up your program (and programming knowledge) gradually.  When something doesn't work, you *know* it's almost certainly the new lines.

Comment: Thank you! I am now having the issue that word is not defined, but I am not sure how else to call the individual words in the string.

Comment: @user8827983: as my update says, this is because you've tried to program several new concepts at once.  You "outran your own legs", as the expression goes.  Take it slowly; if you get stuck on how to define a variable, go back to your learning materials, or find a local tutor.  Such incremental hand-holding is beyond the range of Stack Overflow's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this. It replaces all duplicate words with a dot.

```
lines_test = (["Engineering will save the world from inefficiency.",
               "Inefficiency is a blight on the world and its humanity."])


def solve(lines):
    clean_paragraph = ""
    str_lines = " ".join(lines)
    words_lines = str_lines.replace('.', ' .').split()
    for word in words_lines:
        if word != "." and word.lower() in clean_paragraph.lower():
            word = " ."
        elif word != ".":
            word = " " + word
        clean_paragraph += word
    return clean_paragraph


print(solve(lines_test))
```

Output:

```
Engineering will save the world from inefficiency. . is . blight on . . and its humanity.
```

It is important to convert words or strings into the lower case or upper case (consistent form) before you make comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way of doing this can be**:

```
lines_test = 'Engineering will save the world from inefficiency. Inefficiency is a blight on the world and its humanity.'

text_array = lines_test.split(" ")
formatted_text = ''
for word in text_array:
    if word.lower() not in formatted_text:   
        formatted_text = formatted_text +' '+word
    else:
        formatted_text = formatted_text +' '+'.'

print(formatted_text)
```

**Output**

```
Engineering will save the world from inefficiency. . is . blight on . . and its humanity.
```